# How to save current URL to a cookie, and restore with javascript onclick

Tags: url, button, cookies, save, restore

Can anyone help me to create a cookie to save the users current URL with location.href when they click a button, in effect a "save progress" button. Then have another load button to take the user to what had been saved in this cookie,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function newDoc()
{
window.location.assign(location.href)
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Load Progress" onclick="newDoc()">

</body>
 </html>
```

is this possible?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create cookie using javascript.

You can use following function to make it easy.
You can read, right, delete cookies by using following functions.

```
/***create cookie using createCookie    later you can read it eg. var url = readCookie("currenturl");***/        

function newDoc(){   createCookie("currenturl", document.URL, 1);  
}

function createCookie(name,value,days) {        if (days) { var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
        }
        else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    }

function readCookie(name) { var nameEQ = name + "=";    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}    

function eraseCookie(name) {     createCookie(name,"",-1);    
}
```